# Why text from SerialPort will break into several parts?

Tags: c#

I used SerialPort to receive text from Handheld Scanner.In addition,the Handheld Scanner is using usb port to connnect with computer but its drivers will make it to a virtual SerialPort.

So I use this code to receive the text:

```
SerialPort serialPort=new SerialPort("COM7");
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort_DataReceived);
private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(serialPort.ReadExisting());
}
```

Well,when I ran the progam,if the barcode is "1234567890",the text what received will break into several parts without rules.
Such as:
123
45
7890

Sometimes such as:
123456
7890

Sometimes such as:
12
34
567890

What's wrong with this,why the text divide into several without rules?How can I let it combine together but not divide any more?

PS:I tried different brand Handheld Scanner,such as Datalogic QD2430/Honeywell GHD1900,but these problem still here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serial port I/O can be thought of as a streaming interface, i.e. You might not receive all the data in a single callback.

When you see:

```
12
34
567890
```

...I suspect what is happening is that your callback is being called three times with 3 `Console.WriteLine` calls. Hence your output looks broken.

Typically you need to read all the bytes until some terminator is reached, which depends on the device.  You will need to buffer the data received until then.  Until then, depending on the nature of the app, you might not be able to process the request.

Comment: I think I should configue the terminator at first,right?

Comment: @102425074 barcode scanners that return numbers usually have the ability yes.  Like I said, it depends on the device

Answer (score 0):

Configure your scanner that after each scan it should add a carriage return and then just get the result like this

```
var result = serialPort.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You mean I write some codes to combine them by split each barcode with carriage?

Comment: I should read the configuration of the barcode scaner carefully first.

Comment: Right, look for adding a suffix

Comment: You probably should point out that **ReadLine** blocks the current thread unlike the OP's original code which is asynchronous